# How to insert content from page by title instead of id in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I want to insert editable content in the header/footer areas of the site.
In the past I set up a folder and used typoscript to get its content like this:

```
lib.header_phone = CONTENT
lib.header_phone {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    where = colPos=0
    pidInList = 12
  }
}
```

But I would like to make this more generic, so it works without updating the pid all the time. Is there a way to get the page by it's title?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to stay at the uid as it's unique. The Title can be present multiple times in the PageTree.

But if you want to have it by title, I think you can edit your where to:

```
where: title=Footer
```

Comment: Well I was thinking to use a very specific title to avoid that problem. Will this work if it's used on multiple sites on the same installation, or is it not smart enough to stay to the current site?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you question. Think you would simply have to try it out. 
Not even sure it will work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i get your question right.
Maybe you should have a look at this documentation:  https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/master/en-us/Installation/InsertingContentPageTemplate/Index.html#based-on-the-fluidtemplate-content-object-cobj

This describes how to render a single column anywhere in a Fluidtemplate. Collect content by title should be avoided and a unique field should be used.

With the example from documentation you can use this line to render your column:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0'}" />
```

you can add this call directly where you want your editable content in header/footer to appear.